R split 1 column into several columns based on regex value
I have dataframe like this



col_names




Aceh..........................................................66.29..........................56.49..........................64.01..................................49.72.....................................39.58...............................52.15


Sumatera.Utara.........................................88.20..........................82.19..........................79.45..................................66.94.....................................53.35...............................73.16


Sumatera.Barat..........................................84.48..........................74.76..........................79.30..................................55.64.....................................44.68...............................78.55



I want to convert into like this



Province
Value_1
Value_2
Value_3
Value_4
Value_5
Value_6




Aceh
66.29
56.49
64.01
49.72
39.58
52.15


Sumatera.Utara
88.20
82.19
79.45
66.94
53.35
73.16


Sumatera.Barat
84.48
74.76
79.30
55.64
44.68
78.55



my code
df$province <- str_extract(df$col_names, '\\w*\\.\\w*')

df$values <- str_extract_all(df$col_names, '[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+')

df <- subset(df, select = c(province, values))

but the values are still in 1 column. I want to separate each of those 6 values into 1 column each.

For example
> read.table(text=sapply(dat,function(x){gsub("\\.{2,}",",",x)}),sep=",")
              V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7
1           Aceh 66.29 56.49 64.01 49.72 39.58 52.15
2 Sumatera.Utara 88.20 82.19 79.45 66.94 53.35 73.16
3 Sumatera.Barat 84.48 74.76 79.30 55.64 44.68 78.55


thank you. the code works well, but can you explain the code? I have another dataframe with 9 values, not 6 values like above

@salmiah-ls Gsub splits row strings based on multiple dots (>=2), sapply applies this to each row, read table puts the output into a data frame.

how if the separator is whitespace like this
1.        Aceh                              52,68      19,91      13,81      13,60     100,00
2.        Sumatera Utara              62,35      16,54      13,72        7,39     100,00
3.        Sumatera Barat              53,98      23,77      12,12      10,13     100,00
I updated the code into this
read.table(text = sapply(df_1, function(x) {gsub('\s{2,}',',',x)}), sep = ',')
but it split even individual number

@salmiah-ls Two things changed, instead of multiple dots you now have one space, and your numbers now have decimal commas instead of dots, so try gsub(" ",";") and sep=";".
